# ASP.NET Web App controller, how to handle errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET Core ASP.NET web application with a controller containing the following code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ConfigurationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Update
            var configurationClient = new ConfigurationClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await configurationClient.SetConfigurationValuesAsync(...);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // How to report back to user?
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The code above calls a Web API and may return an error.

How should these errors be handled in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send some error message via model state dictionary

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  // your other code goes here
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
     // to do : Log errors for you :)
     ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Some error message");       
  }
}
return View(viewModel);
```

Assuming you are using the validation tag helper in the view to render the validation error message to user

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="post">     

    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

    <!-- your input elements here -->
    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use like below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ConfigurationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Update
            var configurationClient = new ConfigurationClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await configurationClient.SetConfigurationValuesAsync(...);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // How to report back to user?

                    return View(viewModel);
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**Brief about return View(viewModel):**

The result object that is prepared by this method is written to the response by the ASP.NET MVC framework when the object is executed.

Comment: Is something missing in the code you provided? I can't see anything done to report any error.

Comment: yup  inside the if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) if you just return the view with the viewmodel then the modelstate error will be display automatically in the view using validation tags

Comment: Yes, but the error is not due to validation errors. It is an error code returned from a HTTP request.